# asp.net/jquery - Countdown timer not working

Tags: asp.net, jquery, timer, countdown

Here is the full code:

```
  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.pack.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        @import "jquery.countdown.css";
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.countdown.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#shortly').countdown({ until: shortly,
            onExpiry: liftOff, layout: "{ps} seconds to go"
        });

        $(document).ready(function () {
            shortly = new Date();
            shortly.setSeconds(shortly.getSeconds() + 5.5);
            $('#shortly').countdown('change', { until: shortly });
        });

        function liftOff() {
            // refresh the page  
            window.location = window.location;
        }   

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <span id="shortly"></span>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I've got the jquery.countdown.js in the Scriptsmap of visual studio. Also the stylesheet "jquery.countdown.css" is in the project.

Don't have a clue about what the problem could be. I'm kind of new to jquery and trying to learn it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with this countdown plugin, but, try moving the part

```
    $('#shortly').countdown({ until: shortly,
        onExpiry: liftOff, layout: "{ps} seconds to go"
    });
```

into the function passed to `$(document).ready`, replacing `$('#shortly').countdown('change', { until: shortly });`

Because otherwise the `shortly` var is not initialized when you're trying to use it.

Answer (score 0):

you have a error in liftOff function with `windowwindow.location`

```
function liftOff() {
    // refresh the page  
    window.location = window.location;
}
```

Comment: Ah didnt notice that, thanks. But still my timer isn't showing.